# Task Scheduler with powershell not working

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008

I need to run via a taskscheduler a simple powershell script that backups my sharepoint farm.

When I copy paste the command on the shell it works perfectly fine.

However on the task scheduler it says parameter its incorrect.

[image]

The command is very simple:

```
powershell -file "\\10.116.2.12\nasbk02\BKPORTAL\BackupFarm.ps1"
```

[image]

Comment: Move everything after `PowerShell` into arguments. So it should be `-File ....` in Add Arguments. If that does not work use the full file path to PowerShell.exe

Comment: What is the ExcecutionPolicy on this server set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All parameters must go into the **Add arguments (optional)** box:

[image]